# automatically duplicate and scatter a shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator

A graphic' worth a million words :
[image]

The red-circled wave (and associated layer) is Illustrator-made.
The other waves were made in Photoshop just to support my problem : this is what I try to achieve in Illustrator.
How can I automatically generate a certain number of copies from one layer (e.g. the wave) and *again* automatically and randomly place them around one position or in another layer (e.g. the ocean) ?

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to accomplish this in Adobe Illustrator is via **Symbols**.

Create a new Symbol from your "wave", then use the **Symbol Sprayer Tool** to "spray" on random instances of the symbol. You can then use the other Symbol tools to alter the set of symbols once in place.

[image]

While not *exactly* automated, it is generally the best you'll get for "random" copies. I'm sure there are scripting solutions, but often it's a fine line between automation and control. Symbols offer just enough control in most cases for me.